# PHP Monolog doesn't store datetime in ISODate format

Tags: php, mongodb, datetime, monolog, mongodate

The PHP IDS system [expose](https://expose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#command-line-filters) uses [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) to store logs into MongoDB. The following is how it stores a log:

```
{
  "message": "Executing on data 4f2793132469524563fa9b46207b21ee",
  "context": [

  ],
  "level": NumberLong(200),
  "level_name": "INFO",
  "channel": "audit",
  "datetime": "1441721696",
  "extra": [

  ]
}
```

I want to use the auto-delete function in Mongo, and I need the `datetime` field to store in ISOdate format, like this:

```
"datetime":ISODate("2015-09-08T17:43:25.678Z")
```

I look at the class `Mongo` in `\Expose\Log\Mongo();` and this is the part responsible for storing the `datetime` in seconds format

```
public function log($level, $message, array $context = array())
{
    $logger = new \Monolog\Logger('audit');
    try {
        $handler = new \Monolog\Handler\MongoDBHandler(
            new \MongoClient($this->getConnectString()),
            $this->getDbName(),
            $this->getDbCollection()
        );
    } catch (\MongoConnectionException $e) {
        throw new \Exception('Cannot connect to Mongo - please check your server');
    }
    $logger->pushHandler($handler);
    $logger->pushProcessor(function ($record) {
        $record['datetime'] = $record['datetime']->format('U');            

        return $record;
    });

    return $logger->$level($message, $context);
}
```

I have changed the $record['datetime'] into this

```
//$record['datetime'] = $record['datetime']->format('U');
$record['datetime'] =  new \MongoDate();;
```

but the time isn't store as ISOdate but this:

```
"datetime": "[object] (MongoDate: 0.84500000 1441721683)"
```

Can anyone tell me how to store the `datetime` in ISODate format?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to use [MongoDate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) to generate the datetime object. eg:

```
$date = new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-11-23 00:00:00"));
```

If you echo this back you will get the format you describe, but internally Mongo should be storing it correctly. To check, you can test:

```
echo date(DATE_ISO8601, ($date->sec);
```

which should return it in a ISO readable format.

Then you can write your own PSR-3 compatible logger that stores data in that manner.

```
$filters = new \Expose\FilterCollection();
$filters->load();
$logger = new \YourCustom\PSR3Logger();
$manager = new \Expose\Manager($filters, $logger);
```

On your Mongo instance you will want to set the TTL on your field like such:

```
db.log.ensureIndex( { "datetime": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

For more info on the TTL setting see the Mongo docs: [Expire Data from Collections by Setting TTL](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a Symfony2 configuration. I solved by setting a custom formatter that basically does nothing. It worked pretty well in my case since I was storing just scalar stuff, the only exception was the **MongoDate** that didn't have to be formatted. So it could be that you may need to do some tuning on your side.

Here's the custom formatter:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service\Formatter;

use Monolog\Formatter\FormatterInterface;

/**
 * Class MongoLoggerFormatter
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Service
 * @author  Francesco Casula <fra.casula@gmail.com>
 */
class MongoLoggerFormatter implements FormatterInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function format(array $record)
    {
        return $record;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function formatBatch(array $records)
    {
        return $records;
    }
}
```

And here's an excerpt of my exception listener:

```php
/**
 * @return \Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger
 */
public function getLogger()
{
    return $this->logger;
}

/**
 * @return \Monolog\Handler\HandlerInterface|null
 */
private function getMongoHandler()
{
    foreach ($this->getLogger()->getHandlers() as $handler) {
        if ($handler instanceof MongoDBHandler) {
            return $handler;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * @return \Monolog\Handler\HandlerInterface|null
 */
private function addDefaultMongoHandlerSettings()
{
    $mongoHandler = $this->getMongoHandler();

    if ($mongoHandler) {
        $mongoHandler->setFormatter(new MongoLoggerFormatter());
        $mongoHandler->pushProcessor(function (array $record) {
            $record['created_at'] = new \MongoDate(time());

            return $record;
        });
    }

    return $mongoHandler;
}
```